# libphonejs - how to use it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, libphonenumber

I've got the following attempt to send an SMS

```js
var number = '**********'

sendText: function(phone, callback) {
        // maybe needs a .then() ?
        var formattedPhone = Phone.format(Phone.parse(phone, 'US'), 'International_plaintext')
        var messageBody = 'test'
        client.sms.messages.create({
            to: formattedPhone,
            from: number,
            body: messageBody
        })
    }, function(error, message) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("SMS ERROR sending to: " + formattedPhone)
            callback(error)
        } else {
            console.log("SMS sent to: " + formattedPhone)
            callback(null, message)
        }
    }
```

It doesn't print an error or a success string to console - is it the Phone.format(Phone.parse()) call that's causing it by blocking the thread or something?

Comment: the number variable is undefined

Comment: it's just a global

Comment: that snippet as it is, is not valid javascript syntax ... so, `sendText` looks like it's supposed to be a property of some object that you haven't shown - how are you calling `sendText`?

Comment: actually, looking at the code again, it's all sorts of wrong and I'm surprised you are not getting any errors in the console ... `sendtext: function(phone, callback) { ...}, function(error, message) { ...}` looks like random code created by mashing fingers on a keyboard

Comment: It's `module.exports = {..., ..., ...}` syntax with a misplaced `})` per function. U sure ur front end m8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax error. The callback function for error message is outside the braces.

https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/api-snippets/blob/master/rest/messages/send-message/example-1.2.x.js

```
 sendText: function(phone, callback) {
            // maybe needs a .then() ?
            var formattedPhone = Phone.format(Phone.parse(phone, 'US'), 'International_plaintext')
            var messageBody = 'test';
            client.sms.messages.create({
                to: formattedPhone,
                from: number,
                body: messageBody
            /*})*/ // remove this should be deleted
        }, function(error, message) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("SMS ERROR sending to: " + formattedPhone)
                callback(error)
            } else {
                console.log("SMS sent to: " + formattedPhone)
                callback(null, message)
            }
        });
  }
```

Comment: You're a god dude, that was so easy to miss after a million hours looking over my codebase.